# how to make columns in table layout spread evenly making maximum use of space available

Tags: android, android-widget

I was just trying out with table layout to display some data....
The data is a 3 column data and i want that the columns should utilize the whole width available. But it seems that the layout XML code which i had used is just wrapping up the columns according to the content.

Layout XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >   
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Address"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Age"
            />  
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try adding `android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"` to your `<TableLayout>` element.

Comment: it Worked.. :)  
thanks....  
can there also be any way so that all columns by itself be in strech mode

Comment: `android:stretchColumns="*"` - that will cause all columns to be stretched by default.

Comment: Is it possible to space out the columns but not stretch their content? i.e., add spaced between them, without affecting their size?

Comment: @AmirRachum you could add Space view's and only stretch those columns?

Answer (score 1):

android:stretchColomns="0,1" is a good option. Also you can try using android:layout_span = "2" This will stretch the columns together depending on your value(Here it will span two columns together)