# what is the best android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I used both RelativeLayout and Linearlayout to achieve this.(in the image)![image]

1. Using relative layout, I positioned the buttons with fixed width, and with marginLeft and marginRight. The problem is, if the device has bigger screen, the left, right margins don't expand much, also the button width is fixed.

   ```
    <RelativeLayout>

       <!-- Row1 -->

   <Button1
     alignParentTop = "true" 
     marginLeft = "5dip"
     marginRight="5dip"
    width="80dip"/>

   <button2
    alignParentTop ="true"
    center="@id/Button1"
    marginLeft = "5dip"
    marginRight="5dip"
    width="80dip" />

   <button2
    alignParentRight="true"
    marginLeft = "5dip"
    marginRight="5dip"
    width="80dip"/>


   <!-- Row2 -->

   <Button3
     below="button1"
     marginLeft = "5dip"
     marginRight="5dip"
    width="80dip"/>

   <Button4
     below="button2"
     marginLeft = "5dip"
     marginRight="5dip"
    width="80dip"/>

       </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Using RelativeLayout parent, created 2 horizontal linearlayout with buttons. Now buttons have 0dip width with weight 1. However, I cannot create the 2nd row.

<RelativeLayout>

   <linearLayout orientation="horizontal">
     <!-- Row1 -->
     <Button1     
     width="0dip"
     weight="1"/>

    <button2
     width="0dip"
     weight="1"/>

    <button2
     width="0dip"
     weight="1"/>
     </linearLayout>
<!--Row2-->
      <linearLayout orientation="horizontal">
     Couldn't using this approach
       </linearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) or [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) as others have suggested, but if you want to modify your LinearLayout solution, you can achieve this with only minor changes. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">   
   <!-- Row1 -->
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
     <Button    
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
   </LinearLayout>

  <!-- Row2 -->
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="3">    
     <Button    
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that the second row's `weightSum` adds up to 3, but each button only has weight 1.

Comment: perfect! I don't prefer GridLayout since it has some space problems. I can certainly try TableLayout, but LinearLayout is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [Gridlayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) to acheive this functionality. Less code to main and better handling of orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you would like to have the buttons stretched out to fill out the screens. Try to use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) instead. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340647/how-to-make-columns-in-table-layout-spread-evenly-making-maximum-use-of-space-av). Basically you use the table rows and columns for you buttons, and specify stretchColumns" to make sure your columns (and therefore buttons) stretch out to fill the space.

Comment: No, in the second row, there are only 2 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As @prijupaul said you can go with a Gridlayout but I would stick for simplicity with the LinearLayout. I don't know why you're wrapping everything in a RelativeLayout, I think you can avoid this.

```
<linearLayout  orientation="vertical">   
   <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
     <!-- Row1 -->
     <Button1     
     width="0dip"
     weight="1"/>

    <button2
     width="0dip"
     weight="1"/>

    <button2
     width="0dip"
     weight="1"/>
   </LinearLayout>

  <!-- Row2 -->
  <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">    
     <Button1     
     width="0dip"
     weight="1"/>

    <button2
     width="0dip"
     weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I use weight=2, it occupies twice the space (2 buttons space)

Comment: I would do something similar to this. But to fix the problem in your comment you can keep the `weight` of the second `Button` at 1 and create an empty `<View`> and give it the same `layout` properties as the `Button`s. If you want an empty space there with the same space